# Text overflow image effect with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Before I begin, I'm not referring to the `text-overflow` ones in CSS. What I'm actually referring to is one of these:

[image: screenshot of a text overflowing an image]

What I'm trying to achieve here is that the text intersects or overflows with the image purposefully. That way, you get this text overflow effect you see from the picture. Any idea how is this achieved using CSS?

Comment: use a background image on a div and add some padding right?

Comment: We need more information. Is the image suppose to be 100% width? You don't want the text to be wrapped, or it is suppose to be wrapped like in the image? You want something like it is in the image, or you want to change something of what you've shown on the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the text in an overlay container, that way, you can add more items if you want. [Demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/delalluyah/pen/dydzQxO)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
}

.container img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.container h4 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  max-width: 60%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2857477/pexels-photo-2857477.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-deepu-b-iyer-2857477.jpg&fm=jpg" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <h4>Apparently, we had reached a great height in the athmosphere
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: absolute;` for the image layer

```css
.container {
  position: relative; /* Add the image and content to be relative */
}

.image-layer {
  position: absolute; /* Make the image flexible in the container */
  top: 0; /* Place the image to the top side of the container */
  right: 0; /* Place the image to the right side of the container */
  z-index: -1; /* Put the image under the main layer which has content */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h1>
      Your text layer for testing purpose
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="image-layer">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" width="500" height="500" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify enough, but I believe you want something like this:

1. Create a div to be used as background
2. Give a background-image to the div created
3. Center the img on the background and give width/height to the div
4. Add text
5. Done

```css
.background {
 background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513530534585-c7b1394c6d51?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixlib=rb- 1.2.1&q=80&raw_url=true&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1471');
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.background > p {
 margin-left: 10px;
 font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
<p>Text over the img</p>
</div>
```

Comment: No, that's exactly not what I want. What I wanted was the image given in the question. The text supposed to overflow, not go inside the image. Sorry, can't take it as an answer :/

Answer (score 1):

Like an option, you can use `grid` approach to make text content to be on front of image with overlaying.
In this case, your text and image will be relevant to each other, see Code snippet for details:

Also, to manage overlay size, you can use CSS variables, like this one `--overlay-size: 10%;`.

```css
.wrapper-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'content'; /* creating grid areas */
  align-items: center;
  
  --overlay-size: 10%; /* overlay size */
}

.wrapper-grid .text,
.wrapper-grid .image {
  grid-area: content; /* use same cell for text and image */
}

.wrapper-grid .text {
  z-index: 1; /* place text in front of image */
  max-width: calc(50% + var(--overlay-size, 0));
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.wrapper-grid .image {
  width: calc(50% + var(--overlay-size, 0));
  justify-self: flex-end; /* aligning image to the right  */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-grid">
  <p class="text">Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue ac venenatis condimentum.</p>
  <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/600/400" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is the one that I want, thank you :D